# How do I get out of FreeDOS and boot the system back up without a hard reboot?

Tags: broadcom

I was running a diagnostic utility from Broadcom on my network hardware and it ran in FreeDOS. I've never used this before and I am unfamiliar with it. Now I am trying to avoid hitting the power button and I would like to boot the system back up normally. How can I do this. I've tried the "exit" command and it didn't do anything.

Comment: What does ctrl+alt+del do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the disk/media and power cycle the machine.  There is nothing special you need to do.